# React Route without Refreshing the Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have below structure for React

```
App.js 
-> 
    Skeleton.js 
    ->
        1) Sidebar.js
        2) Content.js
        -> 
            1) Page1.js
            2) Page2.js
            3) Page3.js
```

Routing is done inside App.js with below:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Fragment>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Skeleton} />  
      <Route path="/:type" component={Skeleton} />
    </Fragment>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

And I have sidebar items like this

```
<ListItem
  button
  className={classes.nested}
  component="a" href="/Equity-Runs"
>
  <ListItemIcon>
    <DescriptionIcon />
  </ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText
    className={classes.child}
    inset
    primary="Page1"
  />
</ListItem>
```

Everything works as expected like, if you click Page1 in the Sidebar it loads Page1, if you click Page2 loads Page 2, etc...

Now, each time you click on a link inside Sidebar, page goes blank white then loads. I'd like to make it so when you click pages only Content.js reloads therefore, rest of the page does not go blank and get loaded. Each time you click on a Page from sidebar, only Content area would change.

I am guessing I would have to move Routing logic into Content file but then problem is I need to know which page the user is on within Sidebar and AppBarPanel files. I don't have Redux set up as of now and would like to not implement that for this question's sake.

Note: I really don't understand why would anyone give negative point to this question without saying what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use a LInk component and not an a if you want the browser router to manage your navigation, as shown here.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-string

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Well how can I make this Link component though?? It's "a" component so it causes page refresh... `<ListItem
                  button
                  className={classes.nested}
                  component="Link"
                  href="/Monthly"
                >
                  <ListItemIcon>
                    <DescriptionIcon />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText
                    inset
                    className={classes.child}
                    primary="Monthly"
                  />
                </ListItem>`

Comment: Answer to my Link component questions is: Add this to the imports `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'` and make sure ListItem has `component={Link}` and change your href to `to="/page-address"`